# Is it "legal" for a conductor to reduce number of instruments in a piece?

Tags: conducting, instrumentation

Is it a common practice for a conductor to reduce the number of instruments? I have an example here:

Wikipedia says that this piece by Mozart was written for 4 horns, but in the video we see only two.

[image]

Comment: I see at least 3 horns in that video. Not in that particular still but if you keep watching. Also what if you just played the melody line on one instrument? Like the composer is dead for more than 200 years so that is safely in the public domain in most countries so legally there's not going to be any problems. It's just a few purists who might cringe if it's not what the artist intended but even back then the performers had some leeway of interpreting their roles.

Comment: @haxor789 - Yes, my bad. There are all four of them there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are definitely four horns in that video.  You can see them in the wide shots just left of the timpani (stage right).  You can clearly see them (well, blurredly) raise their instruments in preparation for their entrance in measure 5.  Another clue that there really are four horns is that they're playing natural horns, and it would not be possible to play the notes we hear in the video with two natural horns.

To answer the question, it's not common practice at the professional level to omit instruments, though it isn't unheard of.  It would typically be done for a specific reason and with some discussion in the program notes (for example to "recreate" a specific performance that was known to have taken place with reduced forces).  Adding instruments or substituting instruments is also fairly uncommon, though any of these would be more likely outside the professional context, for example with a student or community orchestra.

Comment: Other (uncommon, but not so rare) cases for removed instruments, even at professional level: unexpected absence of a musician (due to illness, unexpected events, and even strike) that didn't allow time for substitution; limited size of the performing stage; acoustic choices/requirements; costs (!) especially for large/uncommon/historical instruments that are expansive to rent. It obviously depends on the situation and repertoire (and specific role of that instrument): while it's obvious that removing a violin or two in a section of ten doesn't matter that much, in some cases it's acceptable »

Comment: » to do that even for "solo" parts, especially if the instrument is not a fundamental element or it's always doubling another part. For instance, it's not uncommon to remove certain percussion instruments (if not all!) in opera recitals or programmes with excerpts from that repertoire, because the cost of having some musicians (and large/costly instruments) that may just be needed for one piece and a couple of notes may not be worth the difference.

Comment: Yes, my bad. There are all four of them there.

Comment: @musicamante excellent points, but, in response to "while it's obvious that removing a violin or two in a section of ten doesn't matter that much, in some cases it's acceptable": are you aware of any orchestral work that specifies the number of strings in a section? I am not. The size of the string sections is understood to be the director's choice. Changing it doesn't require rewriting or rearranging the music (as one might rearrange this symphony for a single pair of valved horns). The change of texture is within spec, as it were, unlike omitting an instrument that isn't marked "ad lib."

Comment: @phoog: FWIW that sentence is broken over two comments: "that much, in some cases it's acceptable _to do that even for solo parts_" i.e. the assertion is that it's acceptable (sometimes) to remove solo parts, not that there's a taboo against reducing the size of a large string section :)

Comment: @psmears good catch, thanks.  Even as I was writing that I had in mind rarer situations such as having two or more solo parts in a divided string section -- but practically speaking, any orchestra that would program such a large work would be exceedingly unlikely to do so without having at least a few ripieni in addition to the specified soloists. I mean, suppose there's an orchestral work that has two independent solo parts in each of the two violin sections; a music director probably wouldn't program it for an orchestra with 4 violinists, much less for one with fewer.

Comment: There are substitutions that are routinely made in modern performances by some professional orchestras. Examples that come to mind are the tuba for the ophicleide in music of Berlioz, and the contraforte for the contrabassoon.

Comment: "Student or community orchestra" reminds me of the strings-only community orchestra I was in in my youth, which aspired to play Beethoven symphonies, but had the winds filled in only by a piano. It made the 3rd mov of the Pastoral Symphony amusing, in which you have long horn passages interrupted by three-note asides from the strings.

Comment: To expand on the last paragraph here — In amateur/community settings, playing with some parts omitted or combined (by e.g. two players covering three or four parts) is very common indeed.

Comment: @phoog:  See [this answer](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/119114/21557) for some pieces that specify minimum numbers of string players in each section.  Richard Strauss seems to have done so particularly frequently, but he wasn't the only one.

Comment: @Peter On the London professional scene at any rate, Ophicleide sightings are becoming quite common!

Comment: @phoog Michael Seifert got me before I was able to reply, and, interestingly enough, when I read your comment my first thought went exactly to Strauss. Besides, even if my point (as you've already found) wasn't about that, the conductor doesn't always have full power about the instrument "count", strings section included: they may have some leverage, but the final decision is always up to the production/administration, which may or may not allow more freedom depending on various aspects, mostly based on budget and public image of the orchestra and [host] conductor, but not only.

Comment: @phoog An interesting fact about that and absence due to strikes: I don't know about other countries, but in Italy there are specific "national job contracts" for art workers (orchestra, dance, opera, etc) in important and renown workplaces that specifically forbid hiring another artist/technician if the ones permanently employed are under strike. Even temporary substitutions with existing employees are forbidden: for instance, if the first trumpet is on strike, nobody can replace it, not even the second trumpet player in a piece where only the first is required.

Comment: @musicamante thanks for these additional insights.  I find myself wondering how absolute Strauss would have been about those numbers: suppose the stage could only fit 48 strings instead of 64; would he have accepted that, or would he have maintained that the hall was not an appropriate venue for the piece?

Comment: @phoog He would've probably asked to extend the stage and push players more closer ;-) The fact is that his requirements, while sometimes "bombastic", were perfectly justified for proper equilibrium between sections and to get the proper *sound* from the strings: 16 musicians are *a lot* less, and requires the remaining to "force" some aspects, possibly having a quite different result; so, he wouldn't have probably considered that venue fit for that piece: a performance of the Alpensinfonie was planned during his life, but had to be changed with the Domestica also due to the large orchestra.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing legal or illegal about this. It is not a question of law. You could ask if it is *legitimate* for a conductor to change the number of instruments use. That legitimacy would most likely  be in regard to period practice or instrumentation indicated in a score. Another term to use is *authentic*, as in "authentic performance." But before getting into that you need to know about the classical period and whether an *exact* number of instruments was specified in the score.

The example you give shows that at least four horns would be need to cover the four part harmony, but beyond that the score just says "horns", just simply plural, not a specific number.

One thing to consider, at least from a historical perspective, was where a work was composed and if it was composed for a specific orchestra. That could give some indication of the intended orchestral forces. In the classical era the exact number of instruments used depended on what orchestra was performing. In the case of K. 183, the only thing I could confirm with a few web searches was it was composed in Salzburg, but there isn't any record of its first performance. It seem that it probably wasn't even performed during Mozart's lifetime.

I don't see the point of quibbling about the exact number of instruments in a modern performance for classical works that did not give exact instruments counts and might not have even been performed in a composer's lifetime. How can you confirm exact numbers in such cases?

FWIW, comments suggest you've miscounted the number of horns in the linked Youtube video.

Comment: Yes, my bad. There are all four of them there.

Comment: Is "nothing legal about this" perhaps a typo for "nothing illegal about this"? Or maybe you meant "legal" in the sense of "related to law" rather than "not prohibited by law"?

Comment: @brilliant Re historical perspective: It *is* regular practice to use much modern-size symphony orchestras to play early music that would have premiered with smaller forces. Or at least it has been until the early music movement has made it less common. Bach cantatas often had something like four total violins or one cello, and to mount them with ten times as many is not unusual and definitely changes the effect.

Comment: @TannerSwett, yes, I meant "legality", that's why I ended that sentence with "...sense of...legality"

Comment: @AndyBonner, a long time ago, I think when I was vacationing in Prague, I saw a small theater group do selections from Mozart's Figaro. The orchestra was really a chamber orchestra, something like a string quartet with a winds ensemble. The effect definitely was very different from a large, modern orchestra... but they still they were able to do a performance.

Comment: @MichaelCurtis Or, for a very different period, the original recordings of Rhapsody in Blue, with its paired-down, almost-a-jazz-combo forces. https://youtu.be/VxNbAtTMZXc?si=hvpIKjtFTfMpafl2 see also https://www.loc.gov/static/programs/national-recording-preservation-board/documents/RhapsodyInBlue.pdf Same is also true of Aaron Copland's chamber-ensemble version of *Appalachian Spring*.

Comment: @MichaelCurtis Given the high likelihood of confusion or misinterpretation of your first sentence, I would highly recommend rephrasing.  (Also, the OP put "legal" in quotes, so they're not literally asking about copyright law.)

Comment: a fair number of legal question get asked in this forum and there are lots of questions about "rule breaking". The OP's use of "legal" was kind of vague IMO so I addressed it suggesting "legitimate" instead of "legal."

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to the question is no - there is nothing illegal about changing the instrumentation for music that has gone out of copyright. *)

And for older music it is done in just about every performance of music written about 1930 or older. The reason is that instruments used now are not the instruments the music was written for. As examples:

- Before 1930 or so English composers wrote for small-bore trombones and French bassoons. Both types are different from  the instruments most often used today. The German bassoon is a mid-1800s invention and only slowly moved into some countries -- as an example Stravinsky wrote for the French bassoon.
- The valved horn, the valved trumpet, the tuba and so on are all inventions from circa 1820. Before that valveless horns and trumpets where used. The parts played by the tuba could be written for ophicleide or even serpent (Symphonie fantastique has one Serpent and one Ophicleide, rarely seen in current performances). And the French tuba (high C) that for example Ravel wrote for is very different from the large CC tuba used in most orchestras today, closer to what we today call euphonium in size.
- The violins we play on today with steel strings are quite different from older types. (As a side note, all the Stradivarius instruments have been heavily modified to allow for the higher string tension and longer finger board).
- and so on ...

There are orchestras / performances done on period instruments and they sound quite different from modern instruments.

Additionally, most composers wrote for the orchestras available and probably adapted to what was at hand in the amount of players. I believe that very often contemporary performances had adapted settings. Of course, there were (are)  exceptions, where the composer very specifically asked for certain instruments. Examples include Wagner and his requirement for the so-called Wagner horns.

*) There could be specific license requirements for music or editions that are still in copyright, but that is a different question.

Comment: Thank you phoog for editing. As you might understand English is not my native language.